# stop watch does not show exact time:react js

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to create a stopwatch with minitues seconds and milli seconds  when i click on start i shoud start
i manage to create one but the timing is not correct it takes about 5 seconds to reach 1 sec , also the after 00:60:000 it goes back to 00:00:000

`const [timerState, setTimerState] = useState({});`

```
   const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        setCount((prev) => prev + 1);
      }, 1);
```

```
  const formatTimer = () => {
    let remaining = count;

    const millis = remaining % 1000;
    remaining = Math.floor(remaining / 1000);

    const seconds = remaining % 60;

    remaining = Math.floor(remaining / 60);
    const minutes = remaining;

    return `${minutes.toString().padStart(2, "0")}:${seconds
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0")}:${millis.toString().padStart(3, "0")}`;
  };
```

`<h2>{formatTimer()} </h2>`

also i want to store the formatTimer when stoped into a useState so that i can pass it to a api

the working example i have created a sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-voice-ymo6r?file=/src/App.js:1182-1194

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout`/`setInterval` generally has a minimum enforced delay between invocations, something around a 4ms throttling, but on top of that, the React component lifecycle is optimized for around 60fps, or in other words, about `(1000ms / 1s) * (1s / 60frames)` -> ~`16.666` ms/frame, or basically 17ms per render cycle minimum.

Try a more relaxed interval timing, closer to 4 or 5 ms and you'll see that the stopwatch keeps up more easily, but at this point you are still limited by React's render cycle, so the target interval might be closer to the 17ms timing.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (begin) {
    setTimestamp(new Date().toString());

    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setCount((prev) => prev + 5); 
    }, 5);// <-- use more relaxed interval
  } else {
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  }

  return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current); // <-- clean up previous intervals here
}, [begin]);
```

[image: Edit stop-watch-does-not-show-exact-timereact-js]